# How do i redirect to another html page when i click on the specific data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

Currently I'musing this set of full calendar codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2015-12-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2015-12-07',
                    end: '2015-12-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-12-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-12-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2015-12-11',
                    end: '2015-12-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-12-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2015-12-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2015-12-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-12-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2015-12-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2015-12-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2015-12-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2015-12-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

However i wanted to modify this calendar in such a way that when i click on the particular date, it will bring me to another html page.

i wanted to use this code which i found online

```
 dayClick: function() {
       window.location.href = "testing.html";
 }
```

But it just give me a blank page when i paste it within the code.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but if there is any good answer to my question or any good reference that i can refer to, it would be much appreciated.

The code when the dayclick function is inserted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,

            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

            dayClick: function() {
       window.location.href = "testing.html";
 }
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2015-12-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2015-12-07',
                    end: '2015-12-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-12-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-12-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2015-12-11',
                    end: '2015-12-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-12-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2015-12-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2015-12-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-12-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2015-12-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2015-12-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2015-12-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2015-12-28'
                }
            ]

        });

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <div id="dialog" title="My dialog" style="display:none">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="Id">Id</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <label for="Id">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume that the file `testing.html` exists and has some content?

Comment: What is the url when you go to the empty page?

Comment: http://localhost/test/selectable.html

Comment: @Burki yes is just a simple html page saying hello world and yes is in the same folder.

Comment: If i understand correctly you stay on the same page your calendar was on, only it's empty? Have you checked for JavaScript errors?

Comment: i doubt there will be any errors for the javascript cause i got it directly from
http://fullcalendar.io/download/ directly. is just that i want to add a dayclick function whereby it redirects me to another page when the user click on the specific date.

Comment: This is clearly a situation where doubt does not help much, while a brief look at the console provides certainty.

Answer (score 0):

try with `/` giving some relative context to the url

```
dayClick: function() {
       window.location.href = "/testing.html"; //assuming that testing.html is in same folder as your current html file.
 },
```

or simply use `window.location.replace`

```
dayClick: function() {
       window.location.replace= "testing.html";
 },
```

Comment: whenever i add that line of code in, the calendar does'nt load. hahaha

Comment: @ReubenLee can you share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net? I only edited the code that you said you have found online. you have not used this code in your code either.

Comment: Sorry but i dont really know how to operate the jsfiddle. But anyway, i posted the full code which include the one i found online.

Comment: @ReubenLee are there any errors in your browser's console when you run the code?

Comment: @ReubenLee not on the browser, on the console. press f12 and check.

Comment: oh, it said : SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Comment: @ReubenLee post the full code that you tried. Or i guess you need to put a comma if this was not the last property in the object.

Comment: on this line sir,

       dayClick: function() {
           window.location.replace = "/testing.html";
     }

Comment: yes, right now the calendar came out. However, when i pressed on any of the date, it does'nt redirect me to 'testing.html'. anyway thanks for your patience with me

Comment: @ReubenLee it is difficult to say without seeing your final output html markup. Can you provide the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

add your redirection on select call back

```
select: function(start, end) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    var eventData;
    if (title) {
        eventData = {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end
        };
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

    if(/* your condition here */){
        window.location.href = "testing.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, but would you be able to teach me how to insert the condition part  such that when the user click on any of the date the 'testing.html' page will open?